# Why am i getting "connection reset" error in SQL Server?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, maven, connection

I am trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server. However, I am getting some errors. I tried many things to fix it. Like to check TCP/IP protocols, Java version, password login name etc...

This is my error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset ClientConnectionId:4e2e3738-a56c-4372-9ac8-0dbf0b15a950

For connection reset error, there is no too much information, that's why I couldn't solve the problem. And I don't get it.

Intellij 2022.2
Java JDK: 17
Microsoft SQL Server 2022

This is my code:

connection.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class connection {
    // Connect to your database.
    // Replace server name, username, and password with your credentials
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String connectionUrl =
                "jdbc:sqlserver://LAPTOP-BHJGHRUA\\SQL2022;"
                        + "database=customer;"
                        + "user=username;"
                        + "password=123;"
                        + "encrypt=true;"
                        + "trustServerCertificate=true;"
                        + "loginTimeout=15;";

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);) {
            // Code here.
            System.out.println("connected");
        }
        // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ms</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ms</name>
    <description>Demo project for ms sql</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.1.jre17</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>




    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Might be TLS secure tunnel failure. Try capture the connection packets using Wireshark, see if there is a TLS failure